# Is passing a context as a class parameter safe from leaks?

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I was wondering if in this scenario a delegate class will leak the context

```
class ActivityTracker(private val context: Context?) : Tracker, ActivityLifecycle {
    ....
}
```

As you can see the context is passed to the `ActivityTracker` as a constructor parameter. Will this leak the context if I navigate to another Activity while delegate is still doing some process?

Comment: Why you need the context?

Comment: I need to make my delegate class able to show a toast or invoke a dialog

Comment: Is this going to a be a Singleton class?

Comment: not really I use it in my activity in this way `private val tracker: Tracker by ActivityTracker(this)`